# Using preg_replace with career names and failing at it

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I've got a list of careers and I'm trying to replace them with  tags, for instance:

```
Coach -> <a href='whatever-file'>Coach<a/>
```

However, when a career such as "General Director" comes up, its replaced like this:

```
General <a href='whatever-file'>Director</a>
```

My array containing the patterns goes like this:

```
$patterns=
Array
(
[0] => /\bDirector\b/i
[1] => /\bPresident\b/i
[2] => /\bGeneral Manager\b/i
[3] => /\bConstituency Aid\b/i
[4] => /\bData Input Clerk\b/i
[5] => /\bFront Desk Clerk\b/i
[6] => /\bGeneral Director\b/i
[7] => /\bPlanning Officer\b/i
```

And the replacements is:

```
$replacements=
Array
(
[0] => <a href='#'Director</a>
[1] => <a href='#'President</a>
[2] => <a href='#'General Manager</a>
[3] => <a href='#'Constituency Aid</a>
[4] => <a href='#'Data Input Clerk</a>
[5] => <a href='#'Front Desk Clerk</a>
[6] => <a href='#'General Director</a>
[7] => <a href='#'Planning Officer</a>
```

my preg replace goes like this:

```
$subject = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $subject,1);
```

How can I prevent "Director" from replacing "General Director"?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How long is the list? Can you manually change the `$patterns`? It is much better to put all these into a pattern like `/\b(?:alternative1|alternative2|...)\b/` and then use `$0` backreference in the replacement to refer to the actual match value (you have a case insensitive flag, but you are replacing with hardcoded values)

Comment: The list comes from a DB, I can hardly make any change other than adding the regex operators

Comment: See how you may automate it in my answer. I also added notes for you to understand what the code is doing.

Comment: If this is in a DB can't you just build the link at the query level? `select concat('<a href="#">', name_column, '</a>') as your_link from table`.

Comment: I could but it wouldn't word, because in the DB those names are stored as a string. After I select them, I explode that string to separate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update (wrapping found strings while adding link values to `href`)

You need to create a name-value array from your data, with the search words to be used as keys and replacements as values. Then, you need to sort the array by key length in descending order, and use the keys to build a dynamoc regex like the one in the original answer. To get the url data and paste it into the resulting string, you need to pass the array into a `preg_replace_callback` with the help of `use` keyword.

See the [PHP online demo](https://ideone.com/XzvAhi):

```
$words = array('General', 'Director','President','General Manager','Constituency Aid',
          'Data Input Clerk','Front Desk Clerk','General Director','Planning Officer');
$urls = array('general', 'director','president', 'general-manager ', 'consistency-aid',
           'data-input-clerk', 'front-desk-clerk', 'general-director', 'planning-officer');
$srch = array_combine($words, $urls);

uksort($srch, function($a, $b) {
    if (strlen($a) == strlen($b))
        return 0;
    if (strlen($a) < strlen($b))
        return 1;
    return -1;
});

$pattern= '/\b(?:' . implode("|", array_keys($srch)) . ')\b/i';
$s = "Meet our new General Director!";
echo preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($m) use ($srch) {
    return "<a href='" . $srch[$m[0]] . "'>" . $m[0] . "</a>";
}, $s);
```

## Original answer (wrapping found strings only)

Use a simple `preg_replace` with the following code:

```
$words = array('Director','President','General Manager','Constituency Aid','Data Input Clerk','Front Desk Clerk','General Director','Planning Officer');
usort($words, function($a, $b) {
    return strlen($b) - strlen($a);
});
$pattern= '/\b(?:' . implode("|", $words) . ')\b/i';
$s = "Meet our new General Director!";
echo preg_replace($pattern, "<a href='#'>\$0</a>", $s);
```

See [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/vK59L7)

**Notes**:

- Declare the word array
- Use `usort` part of code to sort the search words in a descending way by length (if `General` comes before `General Director` in the list, you will get `General` wrapped in a tag separately)
- The `/\b(?:alternative1|alternative2|...)\b/i` regex will process all the non-overlapping matches in 1 pass
- `$0` backreference in the replacement pattern will insert the matched variant of the search term (if it is `general director`, it will use it, not `General Director`).

Comment: Great stuff Wiktor! It worked perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: Quick question though, will it be possible to switch the "href" value to a variable instead a plain "#"? @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Yes, what value do you need to put there?

Comment: Each career is stored in the DB with a "url" field. The replacements array contains them, I didn't put them in my original question to simplify. But it goes like this:
    $replacements=
    (
    [0] => <a href='director'Director</a>
    [1] => <a href='president' President</a>
    [2] => <a href='general-manager ' General Manager</a>
    [3] => <a href='front-desk-clerk' Front Desk Clerk</a>
    [4] => <a href='general-director' General Director</a>
    [5] => <a href='planning-officer' Planning Officer</a>

Note: not all the url are just replace the blank spaces with "-"

Comment: @Argus: Please see my update. If it works, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Going to check it now :) i'll let you know

Comment: Update: it worked sir! Thank you very much @Wiktor Stribiżew